# Setting a dataframe columns to type datetime when there are blanks in the columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (`df`) with two columns where the head looks like

```
    name                start                  end   
0   John  2018-11-09 00:00:00  2012-03-01 00:00:00
1  Steve  1990-09-03 00:00:00  
2   Debs  1977-09-07 00:00:00  2012-07-02 00:00:00
3  Mandy                       2009-01-09 00:00:00
4  Colin  1993-08-22 00:00:00  2002-06-03 00:00:00
```

The `start` and `end` columns have the type `object`.  I want to change the type to `datetime` so I can use the following:

```
referenceError = DeptTemplate['start'] > DeptTemplate['end']
```

am trying to change the type using:

```
df['start'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') 
df['end'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

but I think where there are some rows where there are no date in the columns its causing a problem.  How can I set any blank values so I can change the type to date time and run my analysis?

Comment: Perhapes First you need to fill the blank values to  `df.replace(r' ', np.NaN)` and then nan to  fill with fillna like `df.fillna(Timestamp('00000000'))` to process your data.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the `.to_datetime` [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) you can set the behavior using the `errors` kwarg. You can also set the `strftime` format with the `format` kwarg.

```
# Bad values will be NaT
df["start"] = pd.to_datetime(df.start, errors='coerce', format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

As mentioned in the comments, you can prepare the column with `replace` if you absolutely must use strftime.